# RPC query for amendment status

Tags: node, voting

What is the node rpc to query about the voting status of the amendment proposals ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently we're in the *proposal* period, and you can look up the number of people supporting a given proposal via the following RPC, where you can see the proposal hash and the number of supporters:

`http://mainnet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/votes/proposals`

```
[
    [
        "Psd1ynUBhMZAeajwcZJAeq5NrxorM6UCU4GJqxZ7Bx2e9vUWB6z",
        614
    ],
    [
        "Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd",
        37
    ]
]
```

Voting periods overview can be found [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/whitedoc/voting.html#periods).